# How to open workbook that contains automatic links to information in another workbook in UIWebview or QLPreviewController

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, qlpreviewcontroller

I try to open an excel document using UIWebview and QLPreviewController.On Opening a document I get a error like this :

[image]

Opening this document is possible using **Office** application but it shows a popup with a warning message message : "**The workbook you open contains automatic links to information in another workbook**"

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe QLPreviewController supports the newer Microsoft formats (*.docx , *.xlsx). And especially they do not work with links to other documents.

If you wanted to accomplish something like this, sadly you are limited to using local HTML files shown in a web view instead.